# Alterar valores dependendo do numero de checkbox selecionados

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho varios checkbox que passam o valor para o input.

*Minha dúvida é a seguinte:*

Se eu marcar os dias Segunda,Terca,Quarta,Quinta,Sexta o `input` apareça: *De Segunda a Sexta*

Se eu marcar os dias Segunda,Terca,Quarta,Quinta,Sexta,Sabado,Domingo o input receba o valor: *Todos os Dias*

Meu [JsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67e1x5af/5/).

Comment: Você só tem essas duas condições?

Comment: teria essas duas mais => de segunda a sabado e outra somente de dia unico, como se tivesse selecionado somente EX: Quinta ou so Sabado etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim segundo suas regras:

```js
var inputs = $('input[name="dias[]"]');
inputs.on('change', function () {
    var str = [];
    var control = 0;
    inputs.each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
         str.push(this.value);
          control++;
        }
    });
    if(control == 7){
     $('input[name="dias"]').val('Todos os Dias');
    }else if(str.join(',') == "Segunda,Terca,Quarta,Quinta,Sexta"){
     $('input[name="dias"]').val('Segunda a Sexta');
    }else if(str.join(',') == "Segunda,Terca,Quarta,Quinta,Sexta,Sabado"){
     $('input[name="dias"]').val('Segunda a Sábado');
    }else{
     $('input[name="dias"]').val(str.join(','));
    }
    console.log($('input[name="dias"]').val());
});
```

```css
#out{width:350px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Segunda">Segunda &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Terca">Terça &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Quarta">Quarta &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Quinta">Quinta &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Sexta">Sexta &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Sabado">Sabado &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Domingo">Domingo &nbsp;
<br>
<input type="text" name="dias" value="" id="out">
```

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo, estava ate montando algo bem similar no php para passar uma ideia melhor. Vou me aprofundar mais em javascript. Vlw

Comment: em vez de colocar `control == 7` ficaria melhor `str.length ==7`?

Comment: A ideia do **control** era inclusive controlar as outras validações mas como as regras são específicas realmente com o **length** fica mais otimizado.